# robotcontrol turn right degrees and move forward , using ROS

Tags: python, ros

I checked the First and Second works great
the Third i got error with

```
    robotcontrol.turn_right(90)
```

AttributeError: RobotControl instance has no attribute 'turn_right'

My Code :

```
from robot_control_class import RobotControl

robotcontrol = RobotControl()

# First, it starts moving the robot forwards while it captures the laser readings in front of the robot.
a = robotcontrol.get_laser(360)

# Then, it checks if the distance to the wall is less than 1 meter. If it is, it stops the robot.
while a > 1:
    robotcontrol.move_straight()
    a = robotcontrol.get_laser(360)
    print ("Current distance to wall: %f" % a)
    robotcontrol.stop_robot()

# third, it turns the robot 90 degrees to the right and starts moving it forwards again.
    robotcontrol.turn_right(90)
    robotcontrol.move_straight()
```

Comment: You’ll need to provide more information, such as what ROS package you’re trying to use. All people can tell you right now is that the method isn’t defined in the class.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using [arnaldojr/Python-3-for-Robotics](https://github.com/arnaldojr/Python-3-for-Robotics/blob/master/robot_control_class.py) . Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/arnaldojr/Python-3-for-Robotics/blob/master/robot_control_class.py#L105), you can see there is no method called `turn_right`. You need to use `turn(self, clockwise, speed, time)` instead.

So something like

```
robotcontrol.turn("clockwise", 90, 1, 1)
```

should solve your problem.